# Exists the android application on double taping the back button error

Tags: android

My android app consists of more than 10 activities.The first activity is a splash screen followed by several activities. my problem is that when I double tap the hardware back button from any of the activities the app  gets closed but when I reopens the app again it is not showing my first activity ie splash screen instead it is showing the second activity.can any one found me a solution regarding this?

this is my first activity

```
public class Firstintro extends Activity
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.thefirst);
    getActionBar().setIcon(
            new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 
           ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
           actionBar.hide();
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Firstintro.this, MainActivity.class);
            Firstintro.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Firstintro.this.finish();
        }
    }, 800);

    }   
}
```

this is my code for exiting the app on double tapping the back button

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
   // long backButtonCount = 1;

    //if(backButtonCount >= 1)
   // {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Try finish(); after startActivity(intent);

Comment: thanks for ur reply.i tried it but it's not working.now it is showing the last opened activity.

Comment: Try Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP also

Comment: sorry.nw its is working thanku so much.but i'have a custom back button in my action bar when i press that button and after that i press my hardware back button the app closes and when i reopens it is showing the previously opened page.

Comment: Edit your question and add those datails

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Firstintro.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finihsh();
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur reply..its not working when i press back button once it is navigating to my splash screen again and again.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onBackPressed()
            {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
             //System.exit(0);

    }
```

and i just add this lines in my manifest file to firstintro activity

```
android:launchMode="singleTask" 
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

and added this line to other activities

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true">
```

now its work perfectly for me..

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this if you want to exit the app completely:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: thanks for ur reply..but this is not working for me if i press my action bar back button and when i double tap the hardware back button the app quits but when i reopens it again its open to some other inner pages.